# How can I put this logo on the left side of the navbar menu?

Tags: html, css

I made a navbar menu and I don't know how to position the logo to the left inside the navbar.

I tried the following:
http://scratchpad.io/nice-slope-1036

The logo itself is round. (width 270px and height 200px)

I expected that the logo would be positioned correctly, but it's under the navbar. And when I move the navbar the logo is visible but then the navbar is broken.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Lambeau_Field.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: dimgray;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: aqua;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="logo2.png" width="270px" height="200px"></a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Liga 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ştiri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Echipe şi jucători</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Statistici</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rezultate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clasament</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Campionate externe</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ştiri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rezultate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clasamente</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Alte sporturi</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: You can float the image left and wrap the ULs in a div

Comment: Wrap everything in a <div> and give it the property of `display:inline-block;`. Then define a class for your `<img>` and give it the property of `float:left`.

Comment: oh,it works.. thank you so much, mplungjan and christopher :)